# How to intercept a RequestBody before RestController and do some business rules handling from another microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Basically, we have a big monolithic application built on Spring Boot v1.2 and we would like to handle some business rules processing from a MicroService (let's call it BR engine) built on Spring Boot v2.1.6.

How can I intercept the requestBody and send it first to BR engine and then once done, it will either proceed to the actual handler (Monolithic Controller) or not based from BR engine results - for simplicity let's say BR engine returns either true or false. If true, proceed to actual handler if false, return an exception.

I wanted to use HandlerInterceptorAdapter however, not sure how I can intercept the requestBody and pass it to a microservice - then from the results it will either proceed or not to the actual handler.

As an example, let's say I have a POST mapping to the Monolithic controller:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<Client> save(@RequestBody ClientDTO dto) {

    log.debug("Saving...");

    Client newClient = Client.builder().build();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(dto, newClient);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(clientService.save(newClient), HttpStatus.OK);
```

}

Now I wanted to intercept the ClientDTO requestBody and send it first to the BR engine and do some stuff from there. I have thought of using an interceptor and add it to my config which implements WebMvcConfigurer. However, I am not sure how can perform a restTemplate here and get a response from BR engine of pass or fail - if fail the actual handler will be skipped and just throw an exception

```
@Component
public class RuleEngineInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

            // intercept requestBody then send it to BR engine
            // but how? and how can I get the response from BR engine
            // to decide whether it will proceed to actual handler 
            // or not - probably return an exception.
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: what are you thinking to add BR engine's response? will it be true and false based on input parameter given to it?

Comment: Hi @YogendraMishra yes it will be true or false only for now depending on the requestBody it can retrieve.